# how to search history in mysql client on macos?

Tags: mysql

I understand that at some point in the 5.x line, MySQL switched from `readline` to `editline` for their shell. I cannot seem to find any references on how to make the history search work in my setup.

```
macos: Ventura 13.2.1
shell: zsh
mysql: 8.0.32
iTerm2: 3.4.19
```

I tried configuring my `~/.editrc` as follows:

```
bind "^c" ed-search-prev-history
```

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> does not do anything inside the `mysql` shell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also on MacOS, and I had to add this line to `$HOME/.editrc`:

```
bind "^R" em-inc-search-prev
```

Comment: I had both the shortcut and the command wrong! Thanks